# Google Script to Parse/Filter Data and Set Several sub SpreadSheets from master Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a master spreadsheet with several drivers and their routes for the day. This needs to be parsed out to several driver sheets. I have one sheet with all the data in the master and another with all the drivers names and spreadsheet ids to run a loop through for all drivers listed. Just runs...no action. Last three comments need to be fixed as well as it errors here and does not like .openById.

```
function setRoutes(){
  var ScheduleSheetURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...";
  var ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ScheduleSheetURL);

  var AllRoutesSheetName  = "RoutesIn";
  var ActiveSheet = ActiveSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(AllRoutesSheetName));  
  var AllRouteData = ActiveSheet.getRange('A:AZ').getValues();

  ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Drivers"));
  //var ActiveDriverCounter = ActiveSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  //var DriverCount = ActiveDriverCounter.filter(String).length;
  var DriverCount = ActiveSheet.getLastRow()-1;

  var idrvSheetID = "";
  var ActiveDriverName = "";
  var RouteData = [];
  var i = 1;

  for (i = 1; i++; i <= DriverCount){

    //Get Route Name
    ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ScheduleSheetURL);
    ActiveSheet = ActiveSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Drivers"));
    ActiveDriverName = ActiveSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    Logger.log(ActiveDriverName);

    //Get Drivers Route
    ActiveSheet = ActiveSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(AllRoutesSheetName));    

    for (var i = 0; i< AllRouteData.length; i++){
      if(AllRouteData[i][1] == ActiveDriverName){
         RouteData.push(AllRouteData[i])
         Logger.log(RouteData[i]);
      }
    }

    ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ScheduleSheetURL);

    //Open & Write Driver Sheet
    ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Drivers"));
    idrvSheetID = ActiveSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
  //  ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idrvSheetID);
  //  ActiveSheet = ActiveSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]);
  //  ActiveSheet.getRange(ActiveSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,RouteData.length,RouteData[0].length).setValues(RouteData);

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet/s you are working on? Also, you don't need to "activate" a sheet or a spreadsheet in order to work on it.

Comment: Due to the sensative nature, I would not be able to provide access the sheets themselves, however could set up samples.

Comment: Due to the storage location, I need an email address to share the link to as it is on my companies domain and it will not allow for public access per GSuite limitations. 

Unless you know a way around this.

Comment: Maybe you could create a simplified copy outside of this domain, without sensitive information, that contains all the relevant data for people to understand the issue?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_MYXr1wsF7UwxCwOmUQagvn8B57deNByNv4AqOIF8w/edit#gid=0 Here is the Master file. Each route link is contained in here. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues:

There are several problems with your script:

- Every time you want to work on a spreadsheet or sheet, you are using some variant of `setActive`. I guess you are under the assumption that you need to "activate" a sheet in order to work on it, but **that's not true!** If you remove all this, your code can be minimized considerably.
- You are not defining the outer `for` loop correctly: `for (i = 1; i++; i <= DriverCount){`. Second parameter should be the `condition`, and third one should be what to do at the end of each loop iteration. You have it the other way around.
- When trying to filter the routes according to the `Driver` (`if(AllRouteData[i][1] == ActiveDriverName){`), you are not specifying the correct array index (arrays are 0-indexed, so `1` here would refer to column B, which doesn't contain the driver's names, so the script won't find any match there.
- You are reusing the same loop counter variable (`i`) in a nested loop (`for (var i = 0; i< AllRouteData.length; i++){`). This will mess with your outer loop.

#### Solution:

Considering all these, I've wrote a small script that accomplishes your purpose. I have changed some of the variables names so that they are more meaningful (please check inline comments):

```js
function setRoutes() {
  const ScheduleSheetURL = "YOUR-MAIN-SPREADSHEET-URL"; // Change to your spreadsheet URL
  const SourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ScheduleSheetURL);
  const RoutesSheet = SourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("RoutesIn");  
  const AllRouteData = RoutesSheet.getRange('A:AZ').getValues();
  const DriversSheet = SourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Drivers");
  const DriverCount = DriversSheet.getLastRow()-1;
  const DriversData = DriversSheet.getRange(2, 1, DriverCount, 2).getValues(); // Get all Drivers data
  for (let i = 0; i < DriversData.length; i++) { // Loop through all Drivers data
    const DriverData = DriversData[i]; // Specific Driver data
    const DriverName = DriverData[0]; // Driver name (column A)
    const DriverSpreadsheetId = DriverData[1]; // Driver spreadsheet ID (column B)
    const DriverRoutes = AllRouteData.filter(routeData => routeData[0] === DriverName); //Filter routes according to driver
    const DriverSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DriverSpreadsheetId); // Get specific Driver spreadsheet
    const DriverSheet = DriverSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; // Get first sheet in Driver spreadsheet
    DriverSheet.getRange(DriverSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, DriverRoutes.length, DriverRoutes[0].length)
               .setValues(DriverRoutes); // Add routes to driver spreadsheet
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will attempt to run this soon!!

Comment: This works, thank you very much. Can you advise how to return specific columns from the data set in a specific order with empty space? Example, Return columns C, B, H, J, empty space, empty space, A.